# Platy has been gravid for over a month

Tags: aquarium, fish, breeding

I’m wondering whether anyone can help me.

I have a platy that seems to have been gravid for over a month. I’m starting to wonder if she is sick, constipated, or if the male we have in the tank is stressing her out.

Her scales appear smooth with no visible illness, but she’s been chasing the male back recently and taking herself off away from him. We have the gravid female platy, male platy and two shrimp in the tank.

I only recently discovered that the place we got the fish from should’ve sold us two females to one male, I don’t know if that makes any difference, but until today he had constantly followed her around the tank.

From what I’ve read, I don’t really fancy putting her in a breeding box and stressing her out, so would moving the male to a separate tank be a kinder option? Also, I haven’t got any peas in at the minute, but I do have broccoli that I can give her to see if that’ll make a difference.

I am still learning about platies and platy care, but I know from reading this and other forums that you guys are better to ask than the place we got them from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Platies, swordtails, guppies, etc. are always carrying young (gravid) once they become adults. If you want to raise platies, I think it is better to put plenty of live plants, floaters like hornwort and *Anarcharis* and some rooted plants.

Young platies and swordtails are pretty smart and fast, unlike mollies, so they do very well if they have plants to hide in. Getting a second tank for babies can start you on the road to addiction (I have 7 full tanks, about 6 empties and 3 ponds).

Comment: About all that needs to be added is  : If male fish are present. Check out "male and female animal breeding interaction" on Wikipedia .

Comment: And ; The fish are not "pregnant"  as a mammal would be. I believe "gravid " is the term used in the tropical fish trade.